# Modulo calculation with inverse and larger divisor

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have this equation $x \equiv (2003^{-1}) \mod 1511$ and am confused with how to try solving it. Since $2003^{-1} < 1511$, you can't use the extended Euclidean algorithm with regards to the inverse. So I'm looking for some tips on where to start with solving this equation. Thanks.

Comment: solve $1511 x + 2003 y = 1.$  Then $2003y  \equiv 1 \pmod{1511}.$  If you find $y> 1511,$ or $y < 0$  use $2003 (y \pm 1511) \equiv 1 \pmod {1511}$

Comment: $2003\equiv492\bmod1511$

Comment: The extended Euclidean algorithm works fine - see the links for that and many other ways to compute modular inverses

Answer (score 0):

since $gcd(2003,1511)= 1$ it has one and only solution

$\Rightarrow $ $2003x\equiv 1mod1511$

($2003mod1511=492)$$\Rightarrow $

$492x\equiv1mod1511$$\Rightarrow $

find the inverse of $492$ in $mod1511$
and you will see its $777$ so

$777\cdot492x\equiv777mod1511 $ $\Rightarrow $

$x\equiv777mod1511$

Comment: note that 777*492=1 because its the inverse

Comment: I am maybe wrong here cause you propanly mean the inverse of 2003 , i will fix this later.